# How to add data to an existing Excel file with PHP?

Tags: php, excel, vba

I have a Excel file with forms and controls. As it is not possible to create a Excel file with forms, controls and VBA code from scratch using PHP, I thought I could upload my empty Excel file to the server, update it and then let the user download it.

I know there are some very good PHP classes as PHPExcel, but I don't know if these classes may append data as said. Does anybody has already done this before?

Answer (score 6):

Think in the other direction!

Instead of pushing data to excel from php, add a data connection to excel that will retrieve its data from a php endpoint taht publish xml.

Don't know if it applies, but it's far more easier to implement.

Moreover, you will have total control on the excel file, keeping all customisations, including VBA.

And finally, you will avoid all messy COM object managing if you end up in this direction.

[Edit] Steps for this solution :

1. Build a php endpoint that publish the XML data (I have actually no php knowledge. Just ensure that calling `yourdata.php` will produce the data in XML).
2. In excel, using a Data connection, insert the content of this XML file: Go to Data TAB (assuming Excel 2010), "From other source", "From Xml data import".
3. let the wizard do the job

After that, you will have a list in Excel, than is linked to your xml source. SImply right lick the list / refresh to get the latest data (or configure the data connection to auto refresh at opening).

Comment: @ Steve B. Would you please explain me better? What do you mean with 'add data connection' and 'retrieve its data from a php endpoint that publish xml'?

Comment: what is your version of excel?

Comment: Normally I use Excel 2003, but I have also Excel 2010. Nevertheless I understood your suggestion.

Comment: This works with Excel 2003 too. I have successfully use this techniques some times ago (don't remember the sequence of click, but you will find useful tutorials quite easily. or you can create the excel file with 2010, and save it in 2003 format).

Comment: @SteveB  Looks like an excellent idea.. but why use xml? i try to use xml but i don't know what format to write the xml in text file? can you explain. can we also just use .csv? as it looks easy to write a simple .csv file. How will the whole solution work.. say i am the user.. who clicks and opens a php page.. and where should the excel template be stored.. and how it will pop to user.. what happens when another user connected to same page, etc. I want to keep pivot tables, excel macros and vba, images and charts in the template file.

Comment: @ihightower: xml is easier to produces than CSV (at least using .Net and C#, which is my primary programming language), but this can works with CSV too I think. Providing the Excel template is easy... simply serve it as a static content, as the excel file is not dynamically generated.

Comment: @MarkBaker and SteveB.. I have made my comments in my own posting below. Please read and advise. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@SteveB Further to my comment and your response earlier.. pls read below.

> @SteveB Looks like an excellent idea.. but why use xml? i try to use
>   xml but i don't know what format to write the xml in text file? can
>   you explain. can we also just use .csv? as it looks easy to write a
>   simple .csv file. How will the whole solution work.. say i am the
>   user.. who clicks and opens a php page.. and where should the excel
>   template be stored.. and how it will pop to user.. what happens when
>   another user connected to same page, etc. I want to keep pivot tables,
>   excel macros and vba, images and charts in the template file. –
>   ihightower
>
> @ihightower: xml is easier to produces than CSV (at least using .Net
>   and C#, which is my primary programming language), but this can works
>   with CSV too I think. Providing the Excel template is easy... simply
>   serve it as a static content, as the excel file is not dynamically
>   generated. – Steve B

---

My finidings..

### XML vs CSV

CSV format for import is only good if Excel Table format is NOT required. You cannot have the alternate rows highlighting, column headers available during scroll, etc.
in summary, for what i found you cannot have external data and table format at the same time.

The error you will get converting the data connection table to "Format as table" is this:

```
 Your selection overlaps one or more external data ranges.
 Do you want to convert the selection to a table and remove
 all external connection?
```

Of course, I do not want that.. but using xml format for import data connection... the table format can stay like this screenshot:

[image: xml data imported from file to Excel]

And, when you scroll past one screen full.. the screen will look like this.. you can see the column headers A, B, C is automatically converted to the data header (ISBN, date, Title, ...)

[image: scrolling the connected xml data past one screenfull]

So, we should go for an xml solution.. which we are figuring out how using php. But, using CSV for testing purposes with about 10 columns x 20,000 rows data.. it works very nicely. The refresh from web server also works very well.

### Put All Piece Togeter

I have had an internal discussion with my team and we think this will really work for us. Now, we are brainstorming on the delivery and flow of user actions to deliver the Excel template reports with data which he generated from php.

### Ok.. What we have in start?

- An Excel Template (e.g. staff_analysis_template.xlsm). This will will have all the pivot table, excel macros, buttons, images, charts, everything an excel file can have in there.
- In the Template file there will be one sheet named "data". This is where the xml or csv import will end up being... readily available for all the pivot tables and charts in the file.
- A php webpage which will have list boxes and text fields for the user to filter on the data.. and he will click search... and this will provide a web page result and and a link to view the same data in the excel template file with all the resulting data in sheet: data.

Here is the Excel Template with sample data.. in this screenshot... you can see

1. **Sheet: data** where the xml data generated from php will be connected and end up in.
2. **Sheet: summary**. where all the formulas in Excel can be used... and
   presented to the user which is based on the data.
3. **Sheeet: Pivot** Can have pivot tables and charts which is based on
   the data and can be made to automatically refresh when the file is
   opened..
4. **VBA** is also available.. for example the button can be used to
   refresh the data or to do any other work.

We can basicially use everything Excel has available for us. The resulting xml file can be left on the webserver.. and also data connection can be an URL also or as a file.

sourceFile="http://xxxxx/test_data3.csv" or

sourceFile="C:\Users\Fiaz\Documents\Magic Briefcase\Learn\excel\test_data3.csv"

[image]

### Need to figure out

The part that are yet to be figured out is how to connect this all together with seamless user experience.. that is the user should not be forced to save the file at first or manually connecting the xml etc.. The excel template must just open right there with the required data and all the analysis available. If user need to save it he will use save as and copy to local machine.

The idea we have for this seamless user experience is like this:

1. generate unique xml data file (e.g. YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_username_pagename.xml) and put it on some tmp server folder.
2. copy the template file to a tmp server folder with update connection of the xml file (for this we need to unzip the .xlsx or .xlsm file), update the connection info in (xl/connections.xml) with the file name and folder: YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_username_pagename.xml then zip it and deliver to user through web as .xlsm or .xlsx

I tried it manually step by step and it really worked.

Will be much appreciated for any ideas on this to make it really better and still keep it simple.

**Feedback required from PHPExcel author @MarkBaker:**

> @MarkBaker: From reading through your comments in other posts for
>   PHPExcel, I understand that we CANNOT do the same using PHPExcel
>   (that is to use the original excel template as it is). So, the solution
>   suggested by SteveB and elaborated by me above seems to be much more
>   powerful for this purpose.  We can keep the original excel template
>   file in tact with ALL THE ASSETS (pivot table, vba, etc.) with in it as it is. The server need
>   not have Excel as well.
>
> **So, can we expect this feature to be available with PHPExcel itself sometime in the future. Then we can be more confident in using the
>   standard technique from the PHPExcel guru himself.**
>
> in my opinion PHPExcel is very useful for invoice type of reports and many others but
>   not for business intelligence type of analysis... which requires the use of pivot tables and complicated charts and code, etc.
>
> Please make your comments.. I will be very interested to see it from your view on how it can be made better.

*Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler.  Albert Einstein*

Comment: Please note: I'm the author of PHPExcel, not php-excel. Support for Pivot tables is on the pipeline for PHPExcel, but unlikely to be done for available (even as an experimental extension) for another 6-12 months. Forms and VBA are unlikely ever to be suported: it's technically possible, but involves just too much work to be practical.

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry.. i have now corrected it to PHPExcel. Can you please make your input about the above solution itself. As this method is far more capable of what PHPExcel can do in a relatively simple way with full support for everything in Excel. Will you ever consider to have this feature be provided with in PHPExcel itself. I am not a php expert (but with Excel, yes) but I do think technically the proposed solution could be builtin with in PHPExcel relatively easily (compared to the scale of work and code already in there). PHPExcel can morph into abv solution to provide better capability.

Comment: For this detailed data analysis purposes... using the excel template as it is for this purpose (WITHOUT ever reading or parsing the file and converting to php objects)... I think much much more can be achieved with no need to re-invent the wheel. Why not Let Excel "by itself" do all its magic.. because no amount of external coding effort could match than using the the built-in excel template file itself. It is also easy to maintain the template file with all of its assets in one place. Comments please from all users for pro and cons.

Comment: This isn't really within the scope of PHPExcel at all: I can't see anywhere that you're accessing the content of the Excel file through PHP In any way, only providing data that is then accessed by the Excel template's own internal scripting to access external data that has been generated by PHP.... as such, it isn't really within the scope of PHPExcel in any way

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for your reply. We use 100% PHP on all our internal web applications used by several departments (100+ users, 10+ major applications written in php ajax). Since we don't have the technial expertise to make a decent report with in a browser using PHP and any of its 10+ frameworks with drill down facility.. easy copy and paste.. etc., data analysis etc. and give FULL power to the users.. we think using the Excel export function from the php application is the best way to go forward. (continued)

Comment: (continued) So, user can continuously use the existing application.. and when detail drill down required.. he can export the data and continue the work forward with Excel. And there is no framework which has the extensive capability of the Excel's data analysis feature and charting with a click of a button. So, in summary.. All this export of data happens from PHP website and continued on Excel from then onwards. With Excel.. now user can do anything with it.. cut and paste to email.. sum up a set of numbers, count it, slice it and dice it in any number of ways imaginable to him. (contd).

Comment: so since there is such use case.. my opinion will be that PHPExcel can   be made to provide this excellent feature.. for PHP users like us who needs the FULL power of Excel and at the same time.. the user first interacts with the data on a PHP page (just as PHPExcel requires it to be). I understand that it is difficult to provide pivot or vba with PHPExcel as you have to write that code. But, with our suggested method that work is made much simplified.. and only the work flow has to be coded without much difficulty. just my opinion for a good use case to have on PHPExcel.

Comment: Pivots will be provided in PHPExcel (as I indicated before) next year.... but the ability to handle VBA scripting within an Excel workbook is a major project and likely to be several man years of work to develop. Your suggested method (as far as I can tell) has no direct interaction of any kind between PHP and your Excel template. I may be missing something here, but PHPExcel is written to provide interaction between PHP and Excel, and I can't see how to modify PHPExcel in any way that would help

Comment: @MarkBaker - are pivots supported in PHPExcel by now? It's already 2,5 years later and I can't find it working.

Comment: @MarkBaker on Sep 10, 2013 you wrote:" Next release is likely to be sometime in October... in addition to the bugs already fixed in the development branch on github, and the pivot tables (which I'll incorporate even if I can't make the cell range changeable), I also have a PR that fixes stock charts that I'm currently testing which are likely to be included." Next release was a year ago and still can't see pivots working

Comment: Well I'm afraid that one man doesn't have all the time in the world to do this..... the pivot table PR didn't work out well, and broke spreadsheets that used any form of styling on save.... and I haven't been able to fix that major issue

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to add with PHPExcel - load file, add data after last row, save file... unfortunately, forms and VBA code aren't supported.

To retain those, you'll need to use COM, which restricts you to a Windows server with MS Excel installed.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is a PHP class PHP, that enables you to build an XLSX (or XLSM, that is XLSX with VBA macros) documents with the technical of templates.

It's very easy to populate a worksheet.
You can also edit forms and VBA since you know their XML structure.

By the way OpenTBS also supports DOCX, PPTX, ODT, ODS, ODP, ...

- [Demo](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo)
- [Doc](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc)

Comment: This answer has been here 8 years and nobody has upvoted it, haha. Well I'll just add the comment that I was able to follow this link, check the live examples, view the underlying PHP code to get it all to work, download it, apply the same code in my project (with one change - had to download one library separately), download the sample template from the website so I could preview how you set up areas within the template for update and get my own project running in about half an hour, all without needing composer. Documentation way better than phpSpreadsheet & far fewer files to include.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually `append` data to an existing excel file.

- Rather load all data from Excel into your array ( easy using PHPExcel );
- Add data to your array ( format it as you want );
- Create a new excel file and let user download it ( or save over the original );

This will simulate append action.

Comment: @ Dainis. I need to keep the VBA code embedded into the XLS file.

Comment: As @MarkBaker said, VBA will be a problem in any option here.